# Couldn't find Listing with 'id'=all, Search Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

So this is very weird.
I followed this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form
and after I implemented everything it looked like this

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag findjobs_path, :method => 'get' do %>
      <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search %>
      <%= submit_tag "search" %>
       </p>
<% end %>
```

listings_controller.rb

```
    def index
    @listings = Listing.all
    @listings = Listing.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    @user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
    @listing = Listing.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.all
    @listings = Listing.search(params[:search])
    end
end
```

listing.rb

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

I get the following error: Couldn't find Listing with 'id'=all
I understand that the find methods looks right away for the id.
I however don't know how I need to set it so that it searches through all my listings.
find_by_all of course does not work.

I hope anyone can help

Thank you so muc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

how about modify listing.rb **search** method?

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    self.where("name like ?", "%#{search}%")
  else
    self.all
  end
end
```

Plus..

listings_controller.rb

```
def index
  @listings = Listing.all 
  # Patching all Listing

  @listing = Listing.where(id: params[:id]) if params[:id].present?
  # Find By Id (For pagination, the 'where' statement result is Listing ActiveRecord::Relationship )
  @listings = @listings.search(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?
  # Search using Keyword
  @listings = @listings.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  # Pagination
  @user = User.find_by_name(params[:name]) if params[:name].present?
  # Find User using name column
  @categories = Category.all

end
```

Comment: I changed it and got a very confusing error about my pagination. I got this error also when I tried to modify the search myself. Here is the new error:
undefined method `total_pages' for #<Listing::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x49176a8>
and it points to this code
<div class="top">
     <nav class="pagination-index">
      <%= will_paginate @listings %> 
    </nav>

Comment: @Rika listing_controller.rb also modify plz :)

Comment: @Rika: The underlying problem is that you're using ancient Rails2 code with Rails4. `Model.find(:all)` doesn't work with Rails4 and was (AFAIK) deprecated in Rails3. You need more up to date tutorial material.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone! This is more than I could have asked for. 
So now the search works and looks for the listing name. What would I need to do different in order to have it search through name, description and location of the listing?